# Apache: help converting .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to convert the following .**htaccess** rewrite rule to the appropriate **NGINX** format.

```
# Redirect /signup/PLANNAME or /signup/PLANNAME/ --> /signup/index.php?account_type=PLANNAME
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^signup/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1 [NC,L]
```

I tried using the following NGINX rule, *but it's not working.*

```
rewrite  ^signup/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1  last;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong to make this work with NGINX? Looking at the [official documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) isn't very helpful since the documentation is not very through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're not within a .htaccess file, you have to use absolute paths. As such:

```
rewrite  ^/signup/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1  last;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was missing the forward slash (/) at the beginning.

Answer:

```
rewrite  ^/signup/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1  last;
```